# Debugging ruby code in irb/pry

Tags: ruby, irb, pry

Is there a way to find out more information of what a method does in irb.

Example would be in irb/pry I could do something like this:

```
strigy_object = "I am string"
```

Now if i type `stringy_object.` and press the tab key, all the possible methods that `stringy_object` responds to would be listed. Since I am relatively new to ruby and not really familiar with all the methods, I would love to possibly find more information about what the method does. In short, is there a `'man'` command equivalent that could help me achieve that in irb/pry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `show-doc` command.

For some commands you'll need to `gem install pry-doc` (like for C commands).

Comment: @ilanberci I actually forgot about that.

Comment: when you get to my age, you forget most things.. (that's why I thank my lucky stars for pry)   :)

Comment: @ilanberci We're the same age, so I'm screwed.

Comment: Hush you whippersnappers, it's my nap-time.

Comment: Thanks guys! show-doc indeed is a lifesaver. I might even go bananas and get the source from github

Comment: @theTinMan Aww dad do we hafta?

Comment: If I could remember what we were talking about I'd say yes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stringy_object.methods`. It will return with all the methods the object responds to.

If you want to trim down that list to only methods specific to that type of object, you can do `stringy_object.methods - Object.methods`.